# Assign values to inner class object

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class like below

```
public class HintQuestion
{
    public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
}
```

and another calss like below

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        HintQuestion = new HintQuestion();
    }
    public HintQuestion HintQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when I create an instance of `User` calss and assign values to inner class object it is not working. I am using object initialize

```
User u=new user{HintQuestion.QuestionCode  ="",...
```

But when I created constructors it's working fine.

Comment: I think you'd need to do `User u = new user { HintQuestion = new HintQuestion { QuestionCode = "", QuestionName = "" } };` or `User u = new user { HintQuestion = new HintQuestion() };`.  You could also try `User u = new User { HintQuestion.QuestionCode = "", };` but I don't know if you'd get an NRE on that or not.  By the way, having the same name variable name as a class name is confusing.

Comment: @Tim I thought having property name as class name is a guideline. If you have only one property with that type. Atleast wpf and winform has many such cases: Visibility, CacheMode, ContextMenu.

Comment: @Atomosk - never worked in WPF, done very little in WinForms.  A quick Google search seems to show WPF at least does that a lot. I still think it's a bad idea, but I'm just one voice of thousands :)

Comment: @Tim actually I was trying `new User{HintQuestion.QuestionCode=""` that was a typo in my question but was not woing

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ - When you did `new User { HintQuestion.QuestionCode=""` did you get an error, and if so what was the error, or did it work?

Comment: @Tim it says `HintQuestion doesn't exist in the current context`

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ - Probably because it hasn't been created yet.  Hence the suggestion to use `new user { HintQuestion = new HintQuestion {....`.

Comment: @Tim it means that object initialize doesn't work for inner class object. Am I right?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ - Essentially yes.  There was no inner class object to initialize.  You need to initialize the instance of the inner object before you can initialize it's properties.

Answer (score 4):

Using an object initializer you have to set the `User.HintQuestion` property the same way as you do in your constructor, assign a `HintQuestion` object to it, which you can also create using an initializer:

```
User u = new User {
    HintQuestion = new HintQuestion { QuestionCode = "", QuestionName = "" }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    public class HintQuestion
    {
        public string QuestionCode { get; set; }
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.HintQuestion = new HintQuestion();
        }
        public HintQuestion HintQuestion { get; set; }
    }


User u = new User { HintQuestion = new HintQuestion { QuestionCode = "test", QuestionName = "test1" } };
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you could add some dialog as to what was wrong so that it's an apparent solution.